# WordPress - show list of PDF files located in Media library?

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody suggest a WordPress plugin (or some code) for displaying a list of PDF's located in the Media library?

I would want to filter the PDF list by name/pattern

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this

```
$args = array(
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_type'=> 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf'
);

$pdf_files = new WP_Query($args);
while($pdf_files->have_posts()) : $pdf_files->the_post();
echo get_the_ID();
//here print what you want
wp_reset_postdata();
```